# How to use C# 4.0 Dll in C# 2.0 dll?

Tags: c#-4.0, c#-2.0

Plugin program could be coded with C# 2.0 or 3.0, not 4.0, so I want to call a dll coded with C# 4.0 in the plugin dll.

I have installed both frameworks.

How can I do that? Thanks.

I tried reference and COM, both are fail.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, you need create new AppDomain and download your plugin into it (please note that you need to subscribe to the events of reference resolution). Another way is another process and interprocess communication.

Answer (score 0):

The CLR is not forward compatible.
Have a look at ths [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxgeneralprerelease/thread/bef443cc-5413-4322-8d9a-117abd2386d3)
The DLL might expose an interface which uses 3.0/3.5/4.0 features, so the caller needs to know the features to use them.
Only way would be to wrap it using unsafe code or a real COM registration as an interface between an intermediary dll and the actual 4.0 dll, but  I agree that providing a clean webservices via WCF is the better solution if you want to have 2.0 callers for a 4.0 dll.
Also note, that you do not need to install CLR 2.0 seperately - it will be installed implicitly when installing 4.0.